# Cannot figure out how to add additional SATA port

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, power-supply, sata

On my Dell Optiplex 7020 Mini Tower, I only have on 6 pin motherboard power to SATA power port. It splits into four different SATA power ports. Unfortunately, one of the SATA power ends broke, so I'm stuck with 3 working ones. I have 3 peripherals (HD, DD, and SSD) and would like to add 2 more internal peripherals (HD and another DD) to it, for a total of 5 peripherals.

I have not found a 6 pin to 5 or 6 SATA port adapter. I'm afraid of underpowering the peripherals though by them all sharing the same motherboard connection. Also I've heard of those horror stories where PC's catch on fire because of splitters, and obviously want to avoid that.

I do have an "Internal USB Connector", as Dell calls it, that the dell agent said could somehow be connected to a HD, although I don't know how (neither did he): https://prm.dell.com/prmPub/cninv000000000008685/9020_mt_systemboardlayout.htm

Edit: https://www.hardware-corner.net/desktop-models/Dell-OptiPlex-7020-MT/ at the bottom of the page, #20 is the connector if the first link didn't work.

I've tried calling Dell and googling, and searching on Amazon for these mystery parts (6 pin to 5/6 SATA , Internal USB Connect to HD). Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There really isn't a safe way to do what you want without a new power supply.  Sadly, Dell is notorious for using their own power supplies, so an off the shelf power supply won't be compatible.  You can get a third-party SATA to USB converter but you will see a significant speed performance hit by doing that.  The link you provided isn't accessible to anyone except a Dell customer.

Comment: @Ramhound Here's another better link: https://www.hardware-corner.net/desktop-models/Dell-OptiPlex-7020-MT/ It should be #20 at the key towards the bottom. So I can't replace the Power Supply at all?

Comment: Even if you were to replace the power supply, it would be with another Dell power supply, and you would be one SATA power plug from your requirement to have 5.